# enzyme is not recognizing lodash.flowright

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, lodash, enzyme, babel-jest

I trying to test a React component which renders a D3 element in another class, below is the component code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {graphql} from "react-apollo";
import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';
import MostConvD3bar from './MostConvD3bar'
import MostConvProdQuery from "../../Query/MostConvProdQuery";
import style from "./MostConvProds.css"

class MostConvProds extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    if (!this.props.loading)
        new MostConvD3bar(this.refs.mostConChart, this.props.products)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (!nextProps.loading)
        new MostConvD3bar(this.refs.mostConChart, nextProps.products)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={style.container} ref="mostConChart"> </div>
          )
      }
 }


const mostConvQuery = {
    name: "mostConvQuery",
    props({ mostConvQuery: { error, loading, mostConverted } }) {
        return {
            loading,
            error,
            products: mostConverted
        }
      }
    }

export default compose(
graphql(MostConvProdQuery, mostConvQuery))(MostConvProds);
```

I have imported lodash.flowright as compose as you can see, but I am getting an error like below.

`TypeError: compose is not a function`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: isn't it `flowRight` - capital **R**, not `flowright`? Also, shouldn't it be `lodash/flowRight` with a forward slash, not a dot?

Comment: Well, the code is running fine, the problem is with the test.

Comment: If you are getting an error, that mean the code doesn't run fine. And if you are NOT importing `flowRight` the correct way, that can lead to the error you are seeing.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.flowright

Comment: I took you suggestion and changed it to 'lodash/flowRight' , I got the same error again, but the code is running as though nothing changed.

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1286   Replacing           
 `import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';`  with                                      
` import { flowRight } from "lodash";`    solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

<s>`import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';`</s>

with:

```
import { flowRight as compose } from 'lodash';
```